# Getting user password from Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I am using active directory in my ASP.NET project and whenever user register in the site,an account is created in AD. There is an Forgot Password link.Is it possible to get user password from AD.I can get the name or email, but I don't know if I can get the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is impossible. I would suggest that you do not implement 'forgot password' functionality, but rather 'reset password'. You generate a new password, reset the password in Active Directory and send the new password to the user.

**EDIT**: Based on the information in your comment. First of all, it is a *very* bad idea to use an administrator account the way you use it now, with the account name and password as part of your code. You're running an ASP.NET site, so you should configure the application pool to run with this account.

Second, you should simply create a `DirectoryEntry` with the correct path and reset the password. I'm not sure what your `oEntry` is:

```
var userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
    "LDAP://CN=SomeUser,OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=com");
using (userEntry)
{
    userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "NewPassword" });
    userEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: if i want to reset password programatically,then we have to user old password for accessing the user from AD? Then how we can reset the password. Is there any other method than i choosen

Comment: @Abhimanyu - You don't need the old user password to reset a password. You just need sufficient rights (Account Operator).

Comment: I am using the following code to reset,       DirectoryEntry oEntry = new DirectoryEntry("path", "admin", "pwd");

        DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(Label2.Text);
        uEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPwd });
        uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account

        uEntry.Close();                                              but it's not working.I am giving the sufficient rights

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get existing password for users from active directory since it is hashed with sid. But you can get new password that are going to set for users in AD. For that you need to register a password filter in every domain controller. Whenever password change request come to dc it will invoke registered password filter on both pre , post password change to User.

Refer link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882(v=vs.85).aspx